# On the current interest in COM

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am starting to do some development in C++ which includes the use of COM interfaces in Windows. I have to make a decision to learn or not to learn the COM technology. So, I want to ask if the COM programming is still widely used or is it rather outdated? Is it still a good idea to invest ones time into learning COM?

Comment: Are you going to be doing any COM programming?  If you are then it seems like it would be a good idea to at least learn a little regardless of it's current popularity.

Comment: I am still not sure if I will. Maybe I will be using only some wrappers, but maybe it is a good idea to learn it to get deeper understanding of those too...

Comment: WinRT, the next version of the Windows api is heavily COM based.  Looks like heady times are ahead for COM.

Comment: If you want to develop in C++ lots of windows code needs COM understanding.. MSXML .. any office automation .. shell extensions etc etc